# Why would a directory have the sticky bit set without the executable bit?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, directory-structure, sticky-bit

In Ubuntu 14.04, listing the contents of the directory `/var/spool/cron` with `ls -l` provides the following permissions on the directories within (irrelevant columns snipped):

```
drwxrwx--T daemon daemon atjobs
drwxrwx--T daemon daemon atspool
drwx-wx--T root crontab crontabs
```

What purpose does setting a sticky bit on a directory without the executable bit serve?

Comment: But those directories do have executable bits set.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the manual page for `sticky`:

> STICKY DIRECTORIES
>
> A directory whose `sticky bit' is set becomes an append-only directory, or, more accurately, a directory in which the deletion of
>   files is restricted.  A
>        file in a sticky directory may only be removed or renamed by a user if the user has write permission for the directory and the user
>   is the owner of the
>        file, the owner of the directory, or the super-user.  This feature is usefully applied to directories such as /tmp which must be
>   publicly writable but
>        should deny users the license to arbitrarily delete or rename each others' files.
>
> Any user may create a sticky directory.  See chmod(1) for details about modifying file modes.

The upshot of this is that only the owner of a file in a sticky directory can remove the file.  In the case of the `cron` tables, this means that *I* can't go in there and remove *your* cron table and replace it with one of *my* choosing, even though I may have write access to the directory.  It is for this reason that `/tmp` is also sticky.

Comment: Agreed, but I think what's confusing the OP is why this would be done to a directory that isn't world-writeable. Only the user `daemon` and members of that group would be able to do anything in `atjobs` anyway. I assume the devs were thinking of cases where more than that user belonged to the `daemon` group. Can't really think of any other reason to do this.

Comment: In cases where the directory is not world-writable or world-executable, it's simply an additional layer of security in case this is changed by an errant `chmod a+wx`.  This is speculation, but it may be the case that the sticky bit was placed in historical distribution releases, and the owner changed more recently, and there's no reason to _not_ have sticky set in these cases, so "if it ain't broke, don't break it".

Comment: @terdon hits the nail on the head.  I was under the impression that the sticky bit was fairly useless on any directory that wasn't world-writable, and that a capital S or T for the set{u,g}id bits and sticky bit was a warning to get your head out and use them properly.

Comment: @Q23, on the other hand, if the owner or group don't have execute permission, it doesn't prevent _others_ getting the benefit from the setuid or setgid bits. Sure, removing your own execute permission from your own file would be weird, but I don't think it stops the set[ug]id bits from working.

Comment: If the directory is group-writable, it means that group members can't remove each others' files.

Comment: @DopeGhoti The directory is writable for anyone in the `daemon` or `crontab` group respectively - that could be more than one user.

Answer (score 7):

> What purpose does setting a sticky bit on a directory without the executable bit serve?

```
drwx-wx--T 2 root crontab 4096 Apr 24 15:00 /var/spool/cron/crontabs/
```

What you're looking at is similar on Debian. The directory *does* have the executable bit set, for the owner and the group. Just for the owner, sticky doesn't make much sense, since that's by definition only one user (and the owner gets to override sticky anyway). But for the group, it matters exactly as much as for world-writable directories like `/tmp`, namely that regular users can't remove files belonging to other users.

But why would anyone be a member of the group `crontab`?

To be able to modify their crontabs, of course! Debian's `crontab` works
with setgid privilege, thus allowing any regular user to access that directory, with their own UID, and with the GID of `crontab`. That's slightly safer than letting them run `crontab` with set*uid* privilege since keeps the users separated from each other.

```
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root crontab 36008 Jun 11  2015 /usr/bin/crontab
```

Now, normally, the files in the directory are owned and named by their respective owners, and if `crontab` only allows to remove the user's own crontab, there shouldn't be a problem. Having the file permissions set up like that works to protect from bugs in the program, *and* makes the actual UID of the accessing user relevant, not just their *name*.